# 2d Scale width and height based on distance

Tags: 3d, mathematics, linear-algebra, directxmath

I'm drawing a health bar on top of each player. I transform 3d position to 2d. I would like to draw it smaller when distance increases. Any simple math for that? Let's say bar width is 30 and height is 10 it looks good only on distance == 100. What formula should I use to make it decrease in size when distance increases?

Should resolution of the game be taken into consideration?

Comment: This sounds a lot like actual 3D rendering, so any papers/tutorials on it could be useful for you.

Comment: @ZEKE it's about math here, width, height and scale based on distance. Rendering is done in 2D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very *complex* and *hard to understand* calculation people do to get an object's size at a specific distance is: divide by Z. Even the big APIs, like DirectX and OpenGL are basically just rasterizing APIs with a depth buffer. The 3d aspect comes from this. So:

Given a width, a height and a distance from the camera Z, the new width and height of the object is:

```
w' = w / Z
h' = h / Z
```

Comment: One detail, if you find it looks right at its base scale at `referenceDistance = 100` then throw that in as a multiplicative factor:  `w' = w * referenceDistance / distance` - that way the multiplier comes out to 1 at the reference distance you've chosen, and scales appropriately closer & farther away.